# Creating and updateable block on home page of site

Tags: blocks, nodes

I have a 'featured resource' block on the home page of my site. I'd like my very non-technical folks to be able to update this block with a new node every week. Note that it would just display the teaser of the node, with a 'read more' link.

Ideally, it would be easy for them to do this (for example, by just checking a box on the node creation/edit page to add it to the featured resource block).

Anyone have recommendations for the best/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal allows a node to be marked as "Promoted to front page" when editing the page (it's at the bottom, under "Publishing options").

You can make your block from a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

- Enable the Views module.
- Add a new view admin/structure/views/add
- Create a block (untick create a page)
- Click "Continue & edit"
- Add a filter by "Promoted to front page"
- Alter "Use pager" to display 1 item.
- You should already have a sort by post date.
- Save changes.
- Add the block to your home page (it sounds like you already know how to do this, but ask if not).

This view will show the most recent item with promoted to front page set.